# Как можно в коде скопировать всё дерево View элементов?

Tags: android, view, viewgroup

Я хочу сделать автогенерируемое при старте главное меню.

Разметку я создал в `XML`. Когда меня всё устроило, я удалил все пункты, кроме одного.

Я хочу по образцу первого сгенерировать все пункты меню в `onCreate()`.
Пункт меню состоит из:

```
CardView
|
|--RelativeLayout
   |
   |--ImageView 
   |--TextView (опирается слева на картинку ImageView)
```

Контейнер для меню это `RelativeLayout`.

Я пробовал создать `ImageView`, `TextView`, `RelativeLayout`, `CardView`, сделать `addView` одно в другое, но получается не то, ведь новые элементы не копируют настройки старых. Неужели нужно вручную лопатить сеттить все свойства? Даже если и так, то куда сеттить свойство элемента `RelativeLayout` типа `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView`?

Comment: а нельзя создать отдельный xml файл и инфлейтить его?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно либо всё устанавливать руками, либо выделить нужную часть в отдельный xml файл и инфлейтить его (что предпочтительнее)

> Даже если и так, то куда сеттить свойство элемента `RelativeLayout` типа `android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView`

`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`